# Automatically selecting and creating class objects

Tags: c#, java, oop, object

Lets say that we have a box class:

```
class Box
{
    private int width;
    private int height;

    //Box Constructor
    public Box( int height )
    {
        this.height = height;
        width = 450;
    }

}
```

and a series of Box objects in our main:

```
Box Box1 = new Box(147);
Box Box2 = new Box(178);
Box Box3 = new Box(784);
```

Is there a way to use a "for" loop to go through these objects? Also, how would you make the computer create class objects for us? 
eg. create 10 objects using:

```
for( int i=0; i>10; i++)
{
    //method
}
```

Comment: The C++ tag here is irrelevant.

Comment: Choose a language and learn to use the containers it offers you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a collection (or an array, but collections should be preferred generally):

```
List<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<Box>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    boxes.add(new Box(i));
}
```

Comment: List<> is something new to me. I will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You may add all those objects to either array (or) arraylist and loop it.

Example:

```
List<Box> boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
boxList.add(box1);
boxList.add(box2);
boxList.add(box3);

for( int i=0; i < boxList.size(); i++)
{
    //method
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

and in Java you would do

```
Box[] boxes = new Box[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) boxes[i] = new Box(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to group the object together in a list or array.  You can then iterate through the array to create the object and/or use them.

```
Box[] boxes = new Box[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    boxes[i] = new Box(100);  // Create a new box object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to loop through previously created objects, the objects must be in a collection of some sort. It is possible to create objects using a for loop

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    new Box(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid the memory and processing overhead of an ArrayList but using a plain array instead.

**Non iterative creation**

Let's say we know the number of items.

```
Box[] boxes = {
  new Box(1),
  new Box(2),
  new Box(3)
};
```

**Iterative creation**

```
Box[] boxes = new Box[numBoxes];
for (int i=0; i<numBoxes; i++){
  boxes[i] = new Box(i);
}
```

**Iterative access**

```
for (Box b : boxes){
  doWhatever(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference container for the created objects and add them into it. If you need different constructor parameters (as in your example), you will need a container to them:

```
Integer[] boxSpecifications = new Integer[] { 10, 187, 781, 321 };
List<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<Box>();

for (int i = 0; i < boxSpecifications.length; i++) {
  boxes.add( new Box( boxSpecifications[ i ] ) ) ;
}
```